# How to display WooCommerce cart items on the checkout page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shortcode

I'm working on this website where I was asked to add a list of the cart items to the checkout page. I decided to add the

```
[woocommerce_cart]
```

shortcode to the checkout page, above the

```
[woocommerce_checkout]
```

shortcode and simply use CSS to hide the "Proceed to Checkout ->" button in the cart on the checkout page.

However, this has introduced a new problem. Now when shipping is selected on the Checkout page, it defaults to whatever shipping was set for the cart on the Cart page... even when new shipping is selected on the checkout page.

Clearly, this was not the way to add the cart output to the checkout page.

Is there a shortcode just to show the cart items themselves?

What do I need to edit to show the cart items on the checkout page?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, since I solved it with some additional poking around. Hopefully it will help someone else later down the road.

I didn't find a shortcode to to simply add the cart to the top of the checkout page. I had to edit the template file directly.

So, I copied:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php
```

to:

```
/wp-content/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php
```

to make my edits to that file directly so I wouldn't lose them when WooCommerce was upgraded. I then copied the form code from:

```
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart.php
```

And pasted it in the file I copied to my theme directory:

```
/wp-content/mytheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php
```

where I wanted the form to appear.

There may be more elegant ways, but this fixed my issue.

Comment: To get just a list of products with no ability to modify the cart, you can comment out columns and the entire last row to remove the update button. I commented out columns 1,2,4,5 and the last row. For columns, make sure you comment out the header <th> and the contents <td>

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a hook for this

```
// put this in functions.php, it will produce code before the form
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form','show_cart_summary',9);

// gets the cart template and outputs it before the form
function show_cart_summary( ) {
  wc_get_template_part( 'cart/cart' );
}
```

I've created a **cart-part.php** template which contains jus the cart table and replaced the code with **wc_get_template_part( 'cart/cart','part' );**

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is by adding the following code into your **functions.php** file in your child theme.

This way you will not need to add any templates or alter any core woocommerce code.

```
function remove_cart_collaterals() {
    if (is_checkout()) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display');
        remove_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cart_totals', 10);
    }
}
add_action('wp', 'remove_cart_collaterals');
```